# Access to a CTE in my whole stored procedure SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure in which I have a table shows all working days starting from tomorrow to the last date in my records, it works fine, but the problem is I can't have access to it in my SP, I need to make it global and just call it, here is my table contains all the working days:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATE = current_timestamp
      , @EndDate AS DATE = (select max(ASSYDAY.ASSYDATE) from ASSYDAY) 

;WITH dateCTE AS
(
     SELECT @StartDate StartDate, DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@StartDate) wkday
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATEADD(day,1,StartDate) ,  DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(day,1,StartDate)) wkday  
     FROM dateCTE
     WHERE DATEADD(day,1,StartDate) <= @EndDate
)

SELECT StartDate as workingDays 
FROM dateCTE 
WHERE wkday NOT IN(1,7) -- Execluding Sat, Sun
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

and here I need just to say if the dates are in WorkingDays:

```
select wrkTransport.WORKSHOPID from WORKSHOPTRANSPORT wrkTransport
join AddCapacityToCalenders addCapa
on wrkTransport.FACTORYID=addCapa.FACTORYID  ) and wrk.WORKSHOPGROUPID is not null) 
and wrkCalender.DAY>=(select MIN(ASSYDAY) from ASSYDAY where ASSYDATE in (**workingDays**))
```

But I get invalid column name, how can I make it global and have access from all parts of my SP?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above code is product specific.

Comment: @jarlh im using ssms

Comment: So Sql Server right? What version (ie Sql2K22)? Oh BTW SSMS is the IDE for Sql Server.

Comment: You're doing something called a CTE, common table expression. It's only available in that statement. What you can do is to copy it to a temporary table somewhere at the start of your procedure and then use it. For example: create table #t (StartDate  datetime); with cte as ... insert into #t select * FROM cte option(maxrecursion=0)

Comment: ` in (****workingDays****)` is invalid syntax. If you have it like this, it will definitely error out. Otherwise please post the actual SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a CTE it is completed, with the code below you get an temporary table that you can use

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATE = current_timestamp
      , @EndDate AS DATE = (select max(ASSYDAY.ASSYDATE) from ASSYDAY) 

;WITH dateCTE AS
(
     SELECT @StartDate StartDate, DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@StartDate) wkday
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATEADD(day,1,StartDate) ,  DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(day,1,StartDate)) wkday  
     FROM dateCTE
     WHERE DATEADD(day,1,StartDate) <= @EndDate
)
SELECT StartDate as workingDays 
INTO #name_of_temp_table
  FROM dateCTE 
WHERE wkday NOT IN(1,7) -- Execluding Sat, Sun
option (maxrecursion 0);

select wrkTransport.WORKSHOPID 
from WORKSHOPTRANSPORT wrkTransport
join AddCapacityToCalenders addCapa
on wrkTransport.FACTORYID=addCapa.FACTORYID   
  and wrk.WORKSHOPGROUPID is not null 
and wrkCalender.DAY>=(select MIN(ASSYDAY) from ASSYDAY 
  where ASSYDATE in (SELECT workingDays FROM #name_of_temp_table))
```

or you make another CTE and use that like

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATE = current_timestamp
      , @EndDate AS DATE = (select max(ASSYDAY.ASSYDATE) from ASSYDAY) 

;WITH dateCTE AS
(
     SELECT @StartDate StartDate, DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@StartDate) wkday
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATEADD(day,1,StartDate) ,  DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(day,1,StartDate)) wkday  
     FROM dateCTE
     WHERE DATEADD(day,1,StartDate) <= @EndDate
), workingdays as(
SELECT StartDate as workingDays 
  FROM dateCTE 
WHERE wkday NOT IN(1,7) -- Execluding Sat, Sun
)
select wrkTransport.WORKSHOPID 
from WORKSHOPTRANSPORT wrkTransport
join AddCapacityToCalenders addCapa
on wrkTransport.FACTORYID=addCapa.FACTORYID   
  and wrk.WORKSHOPGROUPID is not null 
and wrkCalender.DAY>=(select MIN(ASSYDAY) from ASSYDAY 
  where ASSYDATE in (SELECT workingDays FROM workingdays))
```